# Access iframe content from cross domain

Tags: iframe

I want to hide a button in the `iframe` from my php page. `Iframe` content coming from a different domain. How to access those `iframe` content.
I used the below code to select a button inside iframe using jquery.

```
var iContentBody = $("#iframe_id").contents().find("#search_button").hide();
```

But I did not get any response.

Comment: Can you edit the page in the iframe? In other words, do you own the other site?